# Show that the sequence is bounded above.

Tags: limits, proof-writing, proof-explanation

With $\alpha,\beta$ positive constants, consider the sequence {$u_n$} defined by $$u_1=\alpha,\space u_{n+1}=\sqrt{\beta+u_n} \space\text{for}\space n\in\Bbb{N}$$Prove that if $\sqrt{\beta+\alpha}>\alpha,\space \{u_n\}$ is increasing. Prove (by contradiction) that {$u_n$} is bounded above. Deduce that {$u_n$} has a limit $u$ and find $u$.

I was able to prove that the sequence is increasing by induction, but I'm stuck with the prove by contradiction part. My textbook says to "assume the divergence of this sequence, and show that it follows that $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\to0$, contradicting the monotonic increase." What I don't understand is the relation between the divergence of the sequence and $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\to0$. Can someone explain this to me? Thank you.

Comment: What is $u_n$? What is its connection with the inequality you wrote? Please post the question in a way we can understand.

Comment: I don't think we can help you without knowing what $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $u_n$ are.

Comment: My bad. Just edited. The question should be whole now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $u_n$ unbounded then $u_n \to \infty$ . Then $\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \dfrac{\sqrt{\beta + u_n}}{u_n} = \sqrt{\dfrac{\beta}{u_n^2}+ \dfrac{1}{n}} \to 0$ . Contradiction to the fact that the limit is as least $1$.

Comment: should it not be at most 1?

Comment: @CJC.10 You already know that $u_{n+1} \geq u_n$. So $\frac  {u_{n+1}}{u_n} \geq 1$. That is how you get a  contradiction  from $\frac  {u_{n+1}}{u_n} \to 0$.